# How many tomato plants can I put in a 4 ft. x4 ft. raised bed?

Tags: tomatoes

I would like a mix of cherry and other sizes. Figure indeterminate growth.

Comment: I'm experimenting this year to find out, coincidentally (with about thirty varieties close together). Usually, we give them a lot of space, and it's true, we get plenty of tomatoes from just seven or so plants, though if you pick the wrong variety, you may not get enough. Early Girl and Roma are popular productive plants. I'm also experimenting by planting most of them considerably deeper than usual (they're larger to start with). That way, they have more room to grow. Two, I planted about five feet deep, with a post hole digger. I'm excited to see how they turn out.

Comment: I'm guessing cherry and currant tomatoes would be fine close together, especially determinate ones. Galapagos Island (Solanum cheesmanii) fruits without a lot of soil when grown indoors, but it's indeterminate. So far, in my experiment, only my Galapagos Island and Black Plum (planted fairly deeply) tomatoes are growing fruit, but the others are young yet and there are plenty of flowers. I doubt the roots have interfered with each other, yet. Most of my tomatoes are indeterminate (including Black Plum), aside some Roma-types,but determinate ones are probably a better choice for this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with **five**. You can find many sites that'll tell you that you can space tomatoes as close as 24 inches, 6 to 9 plants in a 4' X 4', but mine always come out stunted when I do that.
One near each corner, and one in the middle should give your indeterminates plenty of room to grow and fruit.
Five happy plants can give you a **lot** of tomatoes.

Comment: I firmly believe anyone that says you can grow tomatoes at 24 inch spacing either A) Has never successfully grown a tomato to full maturity, or B) has never tried harvesting the tomatoes off of a mature plant. Not even considering the potential for them to crowd each other, you still want to be able to get between the plants to harvest them.

Comment: I have three 4x4 beds.  This year, I am growing 7 tomato plants in one and it is simply too much.  I will go back to 4 next year.  It is getting crowded already and we are only a third into the season here in Ohio.